# How to handle missing values in Python that are supposed to be missing (NaNs shouldn't be interpolated)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, nan, missing-data

I am working on a project to model the change in a person happiness depending on many variables.

Most of the explanatory variables are daily (how much food they ate, daily exercise, sleep etc…) but some of them are weekly - and they're supposed to be weekly, and have an effect on the predicted variable once a week.

For instance, one of the weekly variable is a person's change of weight when they weigh themselves on the same day each week.

This data is only available once a week and has an effect on the person's happiness on that day.

In that case, can someone please advise how I can handle missing data in python on the days when there is no data availalbe for weekly variables?

It would be wrong to extrapolate data on missing days since the person's happiness isn't affected at all by those weekly variables on days when they aren't available.

I have created a dummy with 1 when the weekly data is available and 0 if not, but I don't know what to do for the missing data. I can't leave NaNs otherwise python won't run the regression but I can't put 0 since sometimes the actual variable value (ex: change in weight) on the day when the data is available can be 0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way to solve this issue:

- Fill in the NaN with the last value (in this case measured weight)
- Add a boolean variable "value available today" (which was already done as described in the question)
- Add one more variable: (last available value / previous value) * "value available today".

Caveat: modeling a product might prove a little difficult for linear regression algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

SciKit-learn provides classes called Imputers that deal with missing values by following a user-defined strategy (i.e. using a default value, using the mean of the column...). If you do not want to skew training I'd suggest you use a statistic instead of some arbitrary default value.

Additionally, you can store information about which values have been imputed vs. which values are organic using a [MissingIndicator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#marking-imputed-values).

You can find out more about the different Imputers with some example code in the [SciKit-Learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html)

Comment: Thanks Rayan, as I explain in the question, this is not a classic case of missing value. I can't use the mean of the column or anything like that otherwise the model would draw relationship between those inputted values and the predicted variable. It's only weekly that the weight change is known by the person and hence affect their happiness. Not any other days. I've looked for hours yesterday at this issue and all solutions offered for missing values - by imputation for available data - would mess up my model. I've tried using masks too but it didn't change the nans with "something else".